# what is mean app installation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am using `xcode 6.1` and `osx 10.10`. when I am running the app in device, The alert message shows as `"app installation failed"` and `"the packet is unknown"`.my app running in ios simulator bur not not running in the device (ipad 8.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps
1.Check for the certificate 
2.Delete the existing app from the iPad
3.Clean the Project
4.Install the application again

Comment: why is this answer accepted if it doesn't solves your problem?