# What does the installation errror "The packet is unknown" mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to use Xcode 6.2 to install a development build of an iOS app onto my iPod touch (running iOS 8.2).
The installation keeps failing with the message

> **App instalation failed**
>   The packet is unknown.

The console reports the following details:

```
Mar 27 12:53:52 iPod-touch com.apple.StreamingUnzipService[164] <Warning>: -[StreamingUnzipState finishStream]:476: Finishing an incomplete stream! This stream will not be resumable.
Mar 27 12:53:52 iPod-touch streaming_zip_conduit[163] <Warning>: __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke_2:171: Failed to finish extraction: Error Domain=SZExtractorErrorDomain Code=3 "Finishing an incomplete stream! This stream will not be resumable." UserInfo=0x17e33b50 {SZExtractorFunctionNameErrorKey=-[StreamingUnzipState finishStream], SZExtractorSourceFileLineErrorKey=476, NSLocalizedDescription=Finishing an incomplete stream! This stream will not be resumable.}
Mar 27 12:53:52 iPod-touch streaming_zip_conduit[163] <Warning>: secure_send_message:105: Got error 1 from lockdown_send_message
Mar 27 12:53:52 iPod-touch streaming_zip_conduit[163] <Warning>: secure_send_error:137: Could not send error response to host
```

These messages *seem* to imply that the IPA file is somehow corrupted, and can't be extracted, but I had no problem unziping the IPA with Archive Utility on my Mac.

I also already ran `codesign -dvvv on Payload/<my-app-name>.app` and don't see any obvious problems with the certificate used to sign the app.

What does this error message indicate, and how can the issue be resolved?

---

**note**:
I already found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26858040/3938807) but the only current [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858125/3938807) does not help me. Since I have some, possibly relevant, details that may not apply to the previous question, I am asking a new question.

Answer (score 3):

So I was getting this exact error and I tried switching USB ports (from the device plugged into the USB port on my keyboard to the USB port on my laptop) and now it works.